# Get JSON keys' names in Groovy

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter

During JMeter testing I have to get an array of JSON first-level keys' names.
I.e. from JSON like

```
{
    "name": "Sally",
    "address": {
        "country": "Kuba",
        "city": "Havana"
    }
}
```

I want to get

```
<name, address>
```

I'm using Groovy & JsonSlurper, but have no idea, how to get this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already have a JSON object, you can do:

```
println jsonObject.keySet()
```

If you don't, you will need to create one. With the stringfied JSON you can do:

```
def json =  '{"name": "Sally","address": {"country": "Kuba","city": "Havana"}}'
def jsonObject = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
println jsonObject.keySet()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).keySet().eachWithIndex { key, index ->
       log.info('Key ' + index + ': ' + key)
   }
   ```

Explanation:

- `prev` is an instance of [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) which provides access to the parent Sampler result object
- in your case [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) returns "slurped" JSON as a [LazyMap](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.3/html/api/groovy/json/internal/LazyMap.html) so you can access its keys by calling [keySet()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.3/html/api/groovy/json/internal/LazyMap.html#keySet()) function

References:

- [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/)
- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)